# graph store api base Uri

Tags: graphdb

I am using the graph-store api to post rdf data in text\turle format.
For some reason the graph-store api is creating a named graph based on the url that the request is posted on and not the graph name specified with the graph parameter.
For example http://example.com/repositories/testrepo/rdf-graphs/testGraph.

The graphstore controller is logging that it cannot find a parameter baseURI and then proceeds to create a named graph with the url the api was called with.

The swagger spec shows it requires two parameters, the repoID and the graph.
I have tried creating the named graph before posting the data and using the full uri for the named graph in the graph paramter but that makes no difference

The graphcontroller is in a RDF4J package, the source code shows it expects a baseUri parameter in N-3 format?

Tried adding that to the url like so http://example.com/repositories/testrepo/rdf-graphs/testGraph?baseUri=http:\\....
but then I get an error: No parameters expected on a directly referenced graph.

What am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the target graph when importing the date with request like the one below. I guess you are not setting the graph parameter properly and thus the api is using the default one.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/x-turtle" -T turtle_file.ttl -G --data-urlencode "graph=your_graph" http://localhost:7200/repositories/testrepo/rdf-graphs/service
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This worked for me. Alternatively, you can use `http://localhost:7200/repositories/testrepo/rdf-graphs/service?graph=<YOUR_GRAPH_URI>`